# I want to test react API with moxios

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, moxios

I am learning testing with jest and enzyme. I want to test an API with moxios but facing a lot of challenges. I have an API call as below:

```
useEffect(() => {axios.get(`https://API/call/with/dynamicvalue/${id}`,
        {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(getToken())}`,
           },
          }).then((response)=>{
              let MoreData=response.data;
              console.log(MoreData)

        setFullAuditDetails(MoreData.data.slice(0,20).map(d=>{
            return{
            timeF: d.time.split('T')[0],
            actionF: d.method,
            userF: d.userName.split('.')[0]
            }
        }))
    })}, [])
```

I want to test this with moxios. I have done this:

```
const api = `https://API/call/with/dynamicvalue/372c7861-e09a-41ae-8c6d-7bbc7877ad79`

describe("Tests for API", () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install()
})

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall()
  })

  test("Check for the response", (done) => {
    moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.stubRequest(api)
        request.respondWith({ status: 200,         
            response: {  "success": true }
    }) //mocked response
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        expect('status').toEqual('200');
        done();
        wrapper2.unmount();
    })
})
        });
    })
```

Getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'respondWith' of undefined  

  37 |         moxios.wait(() => {
  38 |             const request = moxios.stubRequest(api)  
> 39 |             request.respondWith({ status: 200,       
  
     |                     ^
  40 |                 response: {  "success": true }       
  41 |         }) //mocked response
  42 |         .then(response => {
```

But not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `wait` doesn't return a promise. Check examples in moxios docs how it's done

Comment: I have updated the code as per docs(https://github.com/axios/moxios) but still getting error @EstusFlask

Comment: moxios.stubRequest doesn't return request, you won't see it in docs. moxios.requests.mostRecent() does.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution:

```
describe("Tests for API", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        moxios.install()
    })

      afterEach(() => {
        moxios.uninstall()
      })

      test("Check for the response", (done) => {
        // moxios.wait(() => {
            moxios.stubRequest(api, { status: 200,         
                response: {  "success": true }
        }) //mocked response

        axios.get(api, {  "success": true }).then(response => {
            // console.log(response);
            expect(response.status).toBe(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```